# Getting a list of multiple apps with heroku open

Tags: heroku, deployment

I have a rails project and I've deployed it on heroku. I've had a problem when I've attempted open on browser with `heroku open`, it returns a list looks like following:

```
 ▸    Multiple apps in git remotes
 ▸    Usage: --remote heroku-stagin
 ▸    or: --app still-falls-46284
 ▸    Your local git repository has more than 1 app referenced in git remotes.
 ▸    Because of this, we can't determine which app you want to run this command against.
 ▸    Specify the app you want with --app or --remote.
 ▸    Heroku remotes in repo:
 ▸    still-falls-46284 (heroku)
 ▸    still-falls-46284 (heroku-stagin)
 ▸    still-falls-46284 (still-falls-46284)
 ▸    
 ▸    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments
```

Some commands that I've typed:

- heroku create
- git push heroku master
- heroku open
- heroku open --remote still-falls-46284
- heroku run rails c --app still-falls-46284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to push to your `heroku` server, do:

```
git push heroku master
```

If you're trying to push to your `heroku-stagin` server:

```
git push heroku-stagin master
```

If your `still-falls-46284` branch is also a heroku app and you're trying to push it to that one, do:

```
git push still-falls-46284 master
```